# mongodb flushing mmap takes around 20 secs with no updates being required

Tags: mongodb, mmap

Hi One of our customers is running mongodb V2.2.3 on a 64 bit windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

We're currently seeing mmap flush times of over 20 seconds every minute.
What is confusing me is that it isn't doing any writes to the disk. (Disk write bytes is next to 0)
Our programme which access the data has been temporary turned off.

so all that is connected is a mongo shell.
Mongostat and mongotop aresn't showing anything

The database has 130 million records. There are 356 files for mmap.

Any sugestions on what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Is your Windows server hosted on Azure? If not, what sort of storage do you have?

Comment: The storage is directly to a harddisk. The system is running on a real server.

Answer (score 0):

If your working set is significantly larger than memory, and MongoDB is constantly going to disk for reads (and not just the normal spikes when syncing writes to disk), then you really should be sharding to spread the data across multiple machines/instances.

Comment: Thanks for the general tip, but it doesn't explain why it takes 20 seconds to mmap when mmap isn't writing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Given the behaviour you have described and that you have a large number of files for mmap, I suspect the underlying performance issue is [SERVER-12401](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12401) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker:

> On Windows, Memory Mapped File flushes are synchronous operations. When the OS Virtual Memory Manager is asked to flush a memory mapped file, it makes a synchronous write request to the file cache manager in the OS. This causes large I/O stalls on Windows systems with high Disk IO latency, while on Linux the same writes are asynchronous.

There are a few possible ways to improve the flush performance on Windows, including code changes in both the MongoDB server and the Windows O/S. There is some ongoing work to address these issues, now that the synchronous flushing behaviour on Windows has been confirmed.

If you are using higher latency local storage (for example, spinning disks) you may be able to mitigate the issue by upgrading to SSD or better spec'd drives.

I would suggest upvoting/watching SERVER-12401 and the related Jira issues for updates.

It would also be worth upgrading from MongoDB 2.2 to a newer version as 2.2 is now past end-of-life for updates. There have been two major production release branches since then, including significant improvements in general performance/features as well as Windows support.